# Web.config Error

Tags: web-config

I developed an asp.net application and tested on my pc and every thing works fine. But, when i deployed it on the server it comes up with the follwing error:

Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Just copy the System.Web.Extensions.dll into the bin directory of your web application

Answer (score 0):

You can copy System.Web.Extensions from your local computer to the bin directory of your deployed app.  To set this to be deployed with your application, find them in your project under References, right-click, select properties, and set Copy Local to true.

Another way is to install ASP.NET AJAX on the server.